# I thought I had super natural powers

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Loose means trouble
>
> tight means good
>
> seen with my male
>
> useless without him
>
> stand there in south
>
> lonely, cold and in white
>
> protect when closed, but
>
> opened before fire
>
> can measure well, but
>
> changes scales per material

What am I? Title is included in the riddle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is

> Bolt

Loose means trouble
tight means good

> as in loose screw (no need to explain.)

seen with my male
useless without him

> It is with nut

stand there in south
lonely, cold and in white

> Refers to the [mount bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Bolt) (credits : OP)

protect when closed, but
opened before fire

> may be referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_bolt) : This was my original guess. Thanks OP for clue it refers to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolt_(firearms))

can measure well, but
changes scales per material

> bolt is a unit of measurement used as an industry standard for a variety of materials from wood to canvas(It is also used for fabric)

Title : I thought I had super natural powers

> Cute little dog named 'bolt' from a 2008 [film Bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolt_(2008_film))

Comment: Right answer. But can you try and explain the clue "stand there in south..."? The clue "protect when closed..."  is regarding [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolt_(firearms)).

Comment: Well about south, I got La Bolt the town in South Dakota & Bolt, West Virginia. Is that it? Or do I need to dig deeper?

Comment: No, not La Bolt. Cold, white etc are hints. :) It is easy.

Comment: It has something to do with snow?

Comment: Yes. It is related with snow  :-)

Comment: Mount Bolt (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Bolt)

Comment: Oh! Close I came to is 1. Bolt Snow Boots and 2.Bolt Insulated Snow Jacket. Thanks for the reference. I will edit my answer

Comment: Unfortunate. No Usain Bolt clues...

Comment: @John Usain bolt clue was my hint. If no one answered in couple of days, I would have added that. But as it turns out it was not needed.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is :

> a seat belt.

Because:

Loose means trouble
tight means good

> It obviously must be tight enough.

seen with my male
useless without him

> Need a connector, and useless without it.

protect when closed, but
opened before fire

> When closed with the connector, it protects the driver/passenger.

can measure well, but
changes scales per material

> It also adjusts to the size of the person.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, just couldn't get into a computer. Good guess, but not the answer. Two clues, opened before fire and title is also a clue. Thanks for attempting though :)